# Why do my images within an overflow: hidden container expand downward on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, overflow

Basically, when my images are hovered on, I want them to hover within the container and not bust out, hence the overflow: hidden. The only problem is for some reason, it expands the bottom of the container and bumps into my content below. How can I keep this from happening?

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/addisongabe/pen/YpRVPK?editors=1100)

```
.image-hover-container {
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.inner-container img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
    /*   transform-origin: bottom center; */
}

.image-hover-container img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` on `.inner-container`. i.e

```
.inner-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.image-hover-container {
 
  width: 50%;
   border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  
}

.inner-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-container img {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .4s ease-in;
/*   transform-origin: bottom center; */
}

.image-hover-container img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-hover-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
  <img src="http://addisongabe.com/new/assets/images/store/typecouragements/preview/keep-on-exploring-preview.png" alt="Test Image" />
  </div>
  <p>Hello There</p>
  
</div>
```